# PDF unable to print

Tags: pdf, printer, printing

I have PDF files that can't print.

When i try to print it would give me SAVE AS screen and name of the document with .pm extension.

If I try to save the file with .pdf file it would get corrupted.

I am using  Adobe Reader X on Windows XP. Printer : Xerox Work-Center 5745.

Printer drivers are up-to-date and working fine, also I have the right printer selected for printing.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to install Adobe Reader XI to see if perhaps the problem is solved in the current version?

Comment: Have a look at the document properties, it may have no print permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no permissions use this tools :

http://www.pdfunlock.com/

> Remove passwords and restrictions from secured PDF files!